# Determine the end of a non-sequential multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have this array that I'm trying to process using a `foreach` loop. And I need to call a function when the end of the array is reached. However, I have a problem determining when I have reached the end of the array.

Note: Because of the peculiar nature of what I'm working on, using a `for`, `while` or `do ... while` loop does not come into the equation. I'm stuck with using a `foreach` loop.

Also, if you are suggesting I use PHP's built-in `end()` function, how do I do that? As the function returns the value at the end of the array. In my case, however, the value at the end of my array itself is an array, not a scalar value/variable.

Below is my code and attempts at determining the array's end.

```
$arr = array
(
   0 => array
   (
    'departures' => array('date'=>'23 Feb', 'location'=>'Lagos'),
    'returns'    => array('date'=>'24 Feb', 'location'=>'Abuja')
   ),

   1 => array
   (
    'departures' => array('date'=>'25 May', 'location'=>'Dubai'),
    'returns'    => array('date'=>'1 June', 'location'=>'New York')
   ),

   3 => array
   (
    'departures' => array('date'=>'2 Apr', 'location'=>'Tokyo'),
    'returns'    => array('date'=>'6 Apr', 'location'=>'Seoul')
   ),

   5 => array
   (
    'departures' => array('date'=>'2 Apr', 'location'=>''),
    'returns'    => array('date'=>'6 Apr', 'location'=>'')
   ),

   2 => array
   (
    'departures' => array('date'=>'2 Apr', 'location'=>'LA'),
    'returns'    => array('date'=>'6 Apr', 'location'=>'California')
   ),

   4 => array
   (
    'departures' => array('date'=>'2 Apr', 'location'=>''),
    'returns'    => array('date'=>'6 Apr', 'location'=>'Hong Kong')
   ),
);

$counter  = 0;
$arr_size = count($arr);

foreach ($arr AS $curr_array)
{
   $departures = $curr_array['departures'];

   if( empty($departures['location']) )
   {
      continue;
   }

   if( $counter == ($arr_size - 1) )
   {
      //reached end of array, execute function
   }

   //process array

   $counter++;
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what is the problem/question ? What is your goal?

Comment: @Rizier123,  am trying to determine when I get to the end of the array. Using the counter variable doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You mean when you are on the last iteration?

Comment: @JayBhatt, could you help me with a little more explanatory code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't make it complicated, this should work for you:

Here I first get the last key of your array, by getting all keys into an array with [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and then access the last element of the array == the last key of your array.

After this you can simply check in your foreach loop if the key is equals to the last one.

```
$end = array_keys($arr)[count($arr)-1];

foreach($arr as $k => $v) {

    if($k == $end)
        echo "last one!";
    else
        echo "still going!";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it to a sequential array for the loop

```
$array = array('banana', 'apple', 'orange', 'grape');
$size = count($array);

foreach(array_values($array) as $index => $fruit) {
    if ($index === ($size - 1)) {
        // Last element in the array
        echo "The last fruit is {$fruit}";
    } else {
        echo $fruit.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just stated above that it is non-sequential.

Comment: @NaijaProgrammer then simply convert it to array values for the loop, edited answer.

Comment: Good thing OP doesn't have an associative array !